# Inconsistent date in close description

Tags: discussion, bug, close-reasons, closed-questions

I am talking about this question: [Software Updater is saying "You stopped the check for updates". What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1276498)

[image: Screenshot of part of https://askubuntu.com/q/1276498]

The question was *asked* **11 months ago** and the question was *closed* **12 months ago**.

How is this possible? Is this a bug?

Comment: related from MSE: [Post was closed before it even existed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344532/post-was-closed-before-it-even-existed). If you hover over the dates, you can get an exact date, the question was closed one day after it was asked. The time stamps are strange, I don't understand it myself so read the link.

Comment: Right, the timeline also shows the close date as being one-day-later.  If I had to venture a guess, I'd say that the "rounding" code that displays the "11 months ago" rounds down (to base month), but the "closed date" rounds up.  At this point, we are in the "grey area" where we are just 7 days shy of a year.  I'd expect that on the 21st of this month, both will show "12 months".